# Using function to insert record or return ID value

Tags: mysql

I'm having problems setting up this function to check if a foreign key record exists.

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_city(NAME VARCHAR) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    # initilize variables
    DECLARE ID_FOUND INT DEFAULT 0;

    -- Declare variable to hold results
    ID_FOUND = SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE city_name = NAME;

    -- If records are returned?
    CASE 
      -- Return the foreign key ID found 
      WHEN ID_FOUND >= 1 THEN RETURN ID_FOUND
      -- Insert new record into table
      ELSE INSERT INTO `donorsearch`.`city` (`city_name`) VALUES (NAME);
    END
END//
```

I've tried debugging through PHPMyAdmin but am not sure what the problem is.

Error message: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ') RETURNS INT

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: I just included the error message in the post.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your function had a lot of errors.

```
delimiter //
CREATE FUNCTION find_city(NAME VARCHAR(100)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE ID_FOUND INT DEFAULT 0;

    SET ID_FOUND = (SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE city_name = NAME);

    IF ID_FOUND > 0 THEN 
      RETURN ID_FOUND;        
    ELSE  
      INSERT INTO `donorsearch`.`city` (`city_name`) VALUES (NAME);
    END IF;
END
//
```

Use a tool like *MySQL Workbench* to highlight errors and fix them one at a time.